# Why am I not able to render my header?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, eslint

I'm trying to make `Tech Stack` appear on the top of the `iOS` simulator.  Instead, I'm getting a weird error on both my `.js` files even though they seem syntactically correct.

The error says: `unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body arrow-body-style` on both `.js` files.

I came across this website https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style to get a little more info as well as search SO thoroughly for a solution but couldn't find anything.

(the location of the error is commented in both .js files)

How can I rectify this issue?

Error in simulator:

[image]

Here's `app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import { Header } from './components/common';

const App = () => { // error is on this line
  return (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <View>
        <Header headerText="Tech Stack" />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here's `CardSection.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CardSection = (props) => { // error is on this line
  return (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderColor: '#ddd',
    position: 'relative'
  }
};

export { CardSection };
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that block body is not required use concise body, like this:

```
const App = () => (    // not {, use (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
        <View>
            <Header headerText="Tech Stack" />
        </View>
    </Provider>
);
```

There are two ways of using **[arrow function [MDN Doc]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body)**:

**1- Block Body:** When using `{}` and explicitly return is required inside the body, it is useful when you have some js logic like doing some calculation, creating function/variables.

Example:

```
const Hello = () => {
    const name = 'ABC';
    // other logic
    return (<div> Hello {name} </div>);
}
```

**2- Concise body:** When you want to return something directly, use `()` and return will be not required.

Comment: ah ok, I see!  But whenever I make this change to `CardSection.js`, It won't let me.

Comment: Yeah, same error for some reason.  But it worked for `App.js` without a problem.

Comment: Maybe because, in CardSection, I'm returning something.  In App.js, nothing's being returned.

Comment: write it like this: `const CardSection = props => (
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
       {props.children}
    </View>
);`

Comment: Yeah, for some reason.  I forgot to originally mention that this red error.  (check my original post)

Comment: remove the `{}` here: `export { CardSection };` use this: `export CardSection;` or `export default CardSection;`

Comment: Yeah I tried that before posting the question, it doesn't work :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161752/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-obsolutemal).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have `eslint` enabled for your project. To get rid of this `eslint` error you should wrap your `App` component into brackets like the following

```
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
    <View>
      <Header headerText="Tech Stack" />
    </View>
  </Provider>
)
```

Curly braces is unnecessary in this case.

Hope it will help.